# Laravel 9 Two foreign Keys from the same table

Tags: php, laravel, database, eloquent, laravel-9

I have two tables, banks and Transfers. I am trying to display a transfers table that shows the money transfers between two bank accounts. If I do not use any relationships, then the table shows the appropriate ids, which is means its working fine. The problem comes in is when I want to display the corresponding bank account names.
I get an ErrorException: Attempt to read property "accountName" on int.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eYW5D.png)

Can someone have a look:

This is what I currently have:
**My Bank Model
**

```
class Bank extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $fillable = [
        'accountName',
        'bankName',
        'currencyCode',
        'accountNumber',
        'balance',
        'contact',
        'address',
        'created_by',
    ];
}
```

**My Transfer Model**

```
class Transfer extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $fillable = [
        'fromAccount',
        'toAccount',
        'amount',
        'rate',
        'date',
        'reference',
        'description',
        'created_by',
    ];

    public function fromAccount()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Bank::class, 'fromAccount');
    }

    public function toAccount()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Bank::class, 'toAccount');
    }
}
```

**My Transfers Migration
**

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('transfers', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('fromAccount');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('toAccount');
            $table->float('amount', 15, 4);
            $table->double('rate', 15, 8);
            $table->date('date');
            $table->string('reference');
            $table->text('description')->nullable();
            $table->integer('created_by')->default('0');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->foreign('fromAccount')->references('id')->on('banks');
            $table->foreign('toAccount')->references('id')->on('banks');
        });
    }
```

**My Index Function in the TransferController
**

```
    public function index()
    {
        $transfers = Transfer::with('fromAccount', 'toAccount')->get();
        return view('backend.pages.transfers.index', compact('transfers'));
    }
```

**My View blade file
**

```
@foreach ($transfers as $transfer)
 <tr>
   <td class="fw-semibold">{{ $transfer->date }}</td>
   <td>{{ $transfer->fromAccount->accountName }}</td>
   <td>{{ $transfer->toAccount->accountName }}</td>
 </tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: You named the column `fromAccount` via `$table->foreign('fromAccount')`, but you **ALSO** named the relationship `fromAccount` via `public function fromAccount()` (and the same for `toAccount`). Guess what doesn't work  Maybe do `from_account_id` and `to_account_id`, then `public function fromAccount()` and `public function toAccount()` will work as configured.

Comment: Oh. You are a star. This worked. Thank you very much. Can you put your comment as a answer. Thank you again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a pretty common issue when not using Database conventions for naming. In your case, you've defined the foreign keys in your Migration as:

```
Schema::create('transfers', function (Blueprint $table) {
  $table->unsignedBigInteger('fromAccount');
  $table->unsignedBigInteger('toAccount');
  // ...
  $table->foreign('fromAccount')->references('id')->on('banks');
  $table->foreign('toAccount')->references('id')->on('banks');
});
```

This is fine, but convention suggests that these *should* be `from_account_id` and `to_account_id` (or similar). Again, these are "conventions", not hard-enforced rules.

The issue was that you *also* defined the Relationships **with the same name**:

```
public function fromAccount() {
  return $this->belongsTo(Bank::class, 'fromAccount');
}

public function toAccount() {
  return $this->belongsTo(Bank::class, 'toAccount');
}
```

Due to ordering of operations, when you call something like `$transfer->toAccount` (or `->fromAccount`), you'll get an `integer`. You're correctly expecting it to be a Relationship, like `$transfer->toAccount->accountName`, but you end up calling something like `1->accountName` (`1` being the `id`), and that is not valid.

To handle this, you simply need to use unique names for the columns and relationships. I would suggest, once again to match conventions, the following:

```
Schema::create('transfers', function (Blueprint $table) {
  $table->unsignedBigInteger('from_account_id');
  $table->unsignedBigInteger('to_account_id');
  // ...
  $table->foreign('from_account_id')->references('id')->on('banks');
  $table->foreign('to_account_id')->references('id')->on('banks');
});
```

Then in your model:

```
public function fromAccount() {
  return $this->belongsTo(Bank::class, 'from_account_id');
}

public function toAccount() {
  return $this->belongsTo(Bank::class, 'to_account_id');
}
```

Now, your code should work:

```
@foreach ($transfers as $transfer)
 <tr>
   <td class="fw-semibold">{{ $transfer->date }}</td>
   <td>{{ $transfer->fromAccount->accountName }}</td>
   <td>{{ $transfer->toAccount->accountName }}</td>
 </tr>
@endforeach
```

If you need to reference the `id`s, you'd call `$transfer->from_account_id` and `$transfer->to_account_id`, and your code is no longer "ambiguous".